# Error bind click on jquery check value empty

Tags: php, jquery

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#btnSubmit').bind('click', function(){
        var option = $('#option1').val();
        if(option == ''){
            alert('Answer empty');
        }
        return false;
   }); 
});
</script>
```

...

```
<input type="radio" id="option1" name="option1 />
<input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit" value="submit" />
```

...

> => error click button submit not alert

Comment: then the `$("#option1").val();` is never  `==''` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should modify you code a bit get the value of [`:checked`](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) radio button and if its not checked it means the value is empty and alert the answer is empty

for example

```
$('#btnSubmit').bind('click', function(){
    alert("");
    var option = $('#option1:checked').val();
        if(!option){
            alert('Answer empty');
        }
        return false;
   });
```

here is the working example http://jsfiddle.net/L8VY8/

Answer (score 1):

Because the value of that radio is `on` (default value), look here: http://jsfiddle.net/DV9WP/